# Discrepancy between CodeIgniter active record vs. MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

When I run this query using CodeIgniter's active records:

```
    $user_name  = 'mememe';
    $test = $this->db->select('filename')
                        ->where('user', $user_name)
                        ->order_by('number','asc')
                        ->limit(4)
                        ->get('mytable')
                        ->row('filename');
    print_r($test); exit;
```

I get this result on my browser:

```
5f
```

But when I run the same query on my database manager:

```
SELECT `filename` FROM `mytable` WHERE `user` = 'mememe' ORDER BY `number` ASC LIMIT 4
```

I get this (which is actually correct and what I want):

```
5f
9f
10f
11f
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CI doc

> row()
>
> This function returns a single result row. If your query has more than
>   one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an
>   object.

Jusr remove call to `row` method

```
 $test = $this->db->select('filename')
                    ->where('user', $user_name)
                    ->order_by('number','asc')
                    ->limit(4)
                    ->get('mytable');
```

Answer (score 1):

**row()** method return only first row from your table it is used when you want to get single record you can also get data other row by passing **Row number** row(ROW NUMBER) example `row(4)`

**Another Method**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT filename FROM mytable WHERE `user` = '$user_name' ORDER BY `number` ASC LIMIT 4");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->filename;          
}
```